# Consulta sql a 2 tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando listar resultados de dos tablas relacionadas, pero no soy capaz.

Estas son las tablas simplificadas:

*tabla1*

```
id | fecha
```

*tabla2*

```
id | horario
```

Estoy intentando filtrar los resultados por rango de fechas y poder mostrar la columna horario de la otra tabla.

Mi editor de codigo me muestra en color morado el texto tabla1.id = tabla2.id por lo que supongo que esa parte no estara bien formulada.

```
"SELECT * FROM tabla1 JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.id = tabla2.id WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$fechahoy' AND '$fechahoy' "
```

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo y ayuda

Un saludo,

Comment: Cual es la columna que relaciona tus tablas?

Comment: La columna que relaciona las tablas no tiene por qué *intervenir*  en la consulta (o sea en las columnas que forman parte del `SELECT`) pero sí debe ***existir*** alguna columna que relacione a las tablas entre sí para poder hacer la unión. Son dos cosas totalmente distintas, la condición requerida a solamente la segunda, o sea, que las columnas de relación *existan* realmente.

Comment: Mejor muéstranos la estructura completa de ambas tablas. Si es algo así como un sistema de tareas, órdenes, compras, tiene que haber un id_tarea o similar que relacione la fecha de la tarea con el horario de la tarea

Comment: La columna que relaciona ambas tablas es id. He encontrado un ejemplo usando JOIN pero no consigo adaparlo, modifico la pregunta

Comment: Que error te da? porque ese query esta bien escrito.. salvo, que las dos columnas no sean del mismo tipo

Comment: @gbianchi no me muestra ningún error, al hacer cualquier consulta de fecha siempre aparece 0 coincidencias

Comment: @gbianchi Perdon, si que muestra un error: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\datatable\ejemplo5\index3.0.php on line 165

Answer (score 1):

Xavier hola, según te entiendo quieres unir dos tablas y mostrar los datos de Tabla 1 y algún dato de Tabla 2, filtrando por un rango de fechas.

Creo que esto es lo que quieres ver:

```
" SELECT t1.*, t2.horario
FROM tabla1 AS t1 JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.fecha BETWEEN '$fechahoy' AND '$fechahoy' "
```

Ten presente que el filtro fecha con la clausula BETWEEN te permite filtrar por fecha1 y fecha2, en tu ejemplo la variable fecha parece ser la misma (hoy), si eso es correcto puedes colocar ese filtro de la siguiente manera:

```
... WHERE t1.fecha = '$fechahoy' "
```

Espero haber comprendido y haberte ayudado.
Feliz día..